# Webkit opacity rendering

Tags: html, webkit

[image]

The text on the top has the opacity of 0.5.  The other image has a color of #dddddd (hex).

This is the code I am using:

```
<p style="font:60px Arial;font-weight:bold;opacity:0.5">Hello!</p>

<p style="font:60px Arial;font-weight:bold;color:#888">Hello!</p>
```

The text on the top has jagged edges.  I'm wondering why that is.

Comment: What browser is this? I know Chrome/Win has awful handling of opacity and anti-aliasing

Comment: Try out other browsers. How do they perform?

Comment: The browser I used was Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why that is, but just for testing, try use RGBA instead of opacity (it's better practice after all, yet IE doesn't support it)

http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer could be that the top sample was rendered as black on white (or transparent) with the assumed gamma value for the anti-aliasing based on that.  Once it was rendered on a white background with 0.5 opacity, the values of the pixels would all be increased by 50% and the gamma value would no longer be right to ensure the perception of smooth changes between the pixel values.

At least that's my guess.  Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The way fonts render on browsers depend both of the browser itself and the operating system. That would probably look better on OSX, for instance, because it has a system-wide anti-aliasing.

I don't agree that `rgba` is better practice though, right now `opacity` is a much more reliable solution to implement opacity, in spite of its shortcomings compared to `rgba`. `opacity` is supported on all browsers, even IE 5, but you'll need to add some funky CSS properties to get it to work. [This post](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/) provides a good solution:

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

`rgba` is nice and future-proof, but is not supported in some versions of IE. I only use it when targeting modern devices on responsive design.